# openGL: order independent max blend

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to achieve a certain blend effect, but failing to get it just right:

[image]

On this image you can see 3 "glowy lines" on a black background.

`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA)` is used for blending.

This however has a certain artifact I want to get rid of, the order is apparent and has an effect.

If you look closely you can see that the vertical line was rendered first, as it's sort of occluded by the others and then the red one is rendered. Finally you have the rather overwriting last line, that especially with it's rather opaque center overwrites everything.

The goal is to have effectively a sum of luminosity, the brightest part taking precedence, regardless of render order. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Furthermore, this is part of creating an object that is then rendered as a whole, so it would be possible to render all lines to FBO, do magic (shaders?) and then render the FBO to the scene.

EDIT:
For personal testing; source code and glow line textures for python+pyglet:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44766482/blendtest.zip

A/D keys cycle through destination modes and W/S keys for source modes.
First line you can change the image path, to change between transparency and black in the texture - but the resulting image requires actual transparency as opposed to black.

Comment: Will the lines be only red and white? What gets displayed if you draw a blue line over top of a red line?

Comment: Well to clarify, the lines will be pretty much of any color. Right now they are textured RGBA quads, but other methods of making the glow lines would be acceptable. I have found a few blend modes that work fine on RGB, but I need the black to actually be transparent, so I don't really get further that way. Maybe render to FBO and then somehow restore alpha afterwards?

Comment: Generally, what you want (if I understand correctly) is not easily possible, or not possible at all. Blending works component-wise, so e.g. red (255,0,0) drawn over some shade of azur (180,180,255) will give something "weird" (255,180,255), but not blue, and not the maximum luminosity. You probably need to use a non-RGB color model such as LUV and do a final convert-to-RGB pass. Or, ping-pong, using the texture as shader input.

Comment: You could do that @Damon suggests on a offscreen buffer and render that after composition (convert it to RGB while rendering).

Comment: Here an example of how it could look like:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44766482/test1.png

Problem is, that uses RGB, without alpha. I want the blackness to come from transparency though, as that is required for later blending into the scene.

Red is a bit overshadowed by the white, which is acceptable. It would be perfect if the full red (255,0,0) had the same "priority" as the full white.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you could probably get away with glBlendEquation(GL_MAX); glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);